# Sorting arrays by subarray value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of arrays in javascript with a distance (integer, whole number) value. I am trying to sort them, but I can't seem to get this to work.

```
nodes = [[{distance:15}],[{distance:123}],[{distance:2}]];

function sortNodes(a,b) {
   if (a.distance < b.distance)
     return -1;
   if (a.distance > b.distance)
     return 1;
     return 0;
   }
console.log(nodes.slice(0).sort(sortNodes));
```

Need some direction on what is happening here and why.

Comment: As you say, you have an array *of arrays*. `a` and `b` are *arrays* with one object in them. They're not directly themselves objects.

Comment: `function sortNodes([{ distance: a }], [{ distance: b }]) { return a - b; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do  `return a[0].distance - b[0].distance;` this is because:

1. `distance` is a integer type so you do not need to compare that and return `1`, `-1` or `0` using comparison operator.
2. You have array of arrays with one object inside the nested array so use `[0]` to get that object inside parameter `a` and `b`.

```js
var nodes = [
  [{
    distance: 15
  }],
  [{
    distance: 123
  }],
  [{
    distance: 2
  }]
];

function sortNodes(a, b) {
 return a[0].distance - b[0].distance;
}
console.log(nodes.slice(0).sort(sortNodes));
```

Answer (score 1):

> The comparator function that is passed to the `sort()` function takes
>   the values from the array.

So, as you have mentioned that you have *an array of arrays*, the arguments of the comparator function would be arrays.

Thus, you can use `a[0]` and `b[0]` to access the objects.

Here is the code:

```
nodes = [[{ distance: 15 }], [{ distance: 123 }], [{ distance: 2 }]];

function sortNodes(a, b) {
    if (a[0].distance < b[0].distance) return -1;
    if (a[0].distance > b[0].distance) return 1;
    return 0;
}
console.log(nodes.slice(0).sort(sortNodes));
```

Here is nice de-structuring example:

```
nodes = [[{ distance: 15 }], [{ distance: 123 }], [{ distance: 2 }]];

function sortNodes([a], [b]) {
    return a.distance - b.distance
}
console.log(nodes.slice(0).sort(sortNodes));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
nodes = [[{distance:15}],[{distance:123}],[{distance:2}]];

function sortNodes(a,b) {
    return a[0].distance > b[0].distance;
}
console.log(nodes.slice(0).sort(sortNodes));
```